# Making a PowerShell invoke-restmethod request

Tags: powershell, rest, powershell-7.2

I have been challenged to get a response from an api with powershell.

I have little to no experience with powershell, but have at least been able to get a response from the API provider, but not a response i can use, so i hope someone can help me.
The photo is of the documentaion i have
[Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAd61.png)

What i can't figure out is how i send the message that i want a response for.
The command is the specific api that i need to use, and it has some inputs as seen in the photo.

Input to API:
StreetName
BuildingIdentifier
Floor
Suite
DistrictCode

This is what i got so far.

```
$uri = 'SomeUrl.com'
$command = '/Ois/RealUnit/Address'
$token = 'SomeSecureToken'
$contentType = 'application/json'
$secureToken = ConvertTo-SecureString $token -AsPlainText -force


$webResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $uri -ContentType $contentType -Token $secureToken
write-output $webResult
```

What i know but i don't know how to use or i it has to be used is as follows.

- Request URL: https://SomeUrl.com/Ois/RealUnit/Address
- Response body: is JSON and i only need the response for "unitUse"
- Response Code: I also know that a good response gives the code 200
- Curl: I also know that something called CURL looks a bit like this `curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'StreetName=STREET&BuildingIdentifier=123&Floor=12&Suite=th&DistrictCode=1234' 'https://SomeUrl.com/Ois/RealUnit/Address'`
- Reponse Header: Looks like this
  `{ "access-control-allow-headers": "Content-Type", "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "cache-control": "private", "content-length": "7604", "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8", "date": "Tue, 08 Mar 2022 13:21:27 GMT", "server": "Microsoft-IIS/8.5", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "vary": "Accept", "x-aspnet-version": "4.0.30319", "x-powered-by": "ServiceStack/5.10 NET45 Win32NT/.NET, ASP.NET" }`

Comment: To send a request body, you'd usually opt for a POST request, so change `-Method get` to `-Method Post`, and add `-Body "request body value goes here"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$uri = 'https://SomeUrl.com/Ois/RealUnit/Address'
$token = 'SomeSecureToken'
$contentType = 'application/json'
$secureToken = ConvertTo-SecureString $token -AsPlainText -force
$Body = @{
    StreetName = "STREET"
    BuildingIdentifier = 123
    Floor = 12
    Suite = "th"
    DistrictCode = 1234
}

$webResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -ContentType $contentType -Token $secureToken -Body $Body
write-output $webResult
```

I can't really remember if you have to convert body to JSON data or if the 'Invoke-RestMethod' does it automatically. In any case: this is how you could do it:

```
$webResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -ContentType $contentType -Token $secureToken -Body ($Body | ConvertTo-Json)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks. 
Thoug now when i combine my SomeUrl.com with the command, to this 'SomeUrl.com/Ois/RealUnit/Address'
I get a 404 error as if the requested page does not exsist.

Comment: Well I didn't see you use the $command variable in your Invoke-Restmethod command. Maybe you are doing something else in your live code? But as far as my knowledge of APIs go, you need the full URI. Your CURL example does the same thing. Did you try adding 'https://' in front of the URI? I'll edit my original post, it should be in there anyway.